# convert swf to bitmap

Tags: javascript, php, python, html5-canvas, flash

I am trying to convert my swf to a bitmap images.
I peruse [swftools](http://wiki.swftools.org/wiki/Swfextract)
but it helps to extract all layers of a .swf file such as shapes, jpgs and etc; but I need some images by a specified frame rate. for example 20 images per second from my swf.

I searched alot but it seems that there is no clear way or library. I thought that we can take some snapshot from swf file an a regular period.

please guid me if I have any clear way to do my main convert or if there is no direct way share your opinions.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

Well, python and Flash don't really get along well, but here's one thing you could do. Though, it seems very hack-ish to me.

Using a command line python script and the fabulous [Selenium Webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/), you can open a browser, load the SWF, then [start taking screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python) of a particular screen area.

That's probably the best way I can think of, though this task makes my soul weep.

Answer (score 0):

I found [Gnash](http://gnashdev.org/) that can take screenshot from my .SWF file.

An example is here:

```
gnash --screenshot 1,2,3,4,5 --screenshot-file %f.png  -r 1 test.swf
```

this makes first 5 frame of test.swf and export by names 1.png, 2.png, ...., 5.png