# Selenium downloading different captcha image than the one in browser

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to download a captcha image with Selenium, however, I'm getting a different image downloaded than the one showed in the browser.
If I try to download the image again, without changing the browser, I get a different one.

Any thoughts?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

# Change frame.
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")


# Download image/captcha.
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='trRandom3']/td[2]/img")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.jpeg")
```

Comment: The src for the image is not necessarily (and is probably not) a file on disk but is likely a dynamically generated image.  Every time the endpoint is requested, a new image is created and the "answer" to the CAPTCHA is stored in your session.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because the link of image's `src` gives you a random **new** captcha image once you open that link!

Instead of download the file from the image's `src`, you can take a screenshot to get the one in browser. However, you need to download `Pillow` (`pip install Pillow`) and use it like the way mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15870708/5299236):

```
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver

def get_captcha(driver, element, path):
    # now that we have the preliminary stuff out of the way time to get that image :D
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    # saves screenshot of entire page
    driver.save_screenshot(path)

    # uses PIL library to open image in memory
    image = Image.open(path)

    left = location['x']
    top = location['y'] + 140
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height'] + 140

    image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
    image.save(path, 'jpeg')  # saves new cropped image


driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

# change frame
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")

# download image/captcha
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='trRandom3']/td[2]/img")
get_captcha(driver, img, "captcha.jpeg")



driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

# change frame
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")

# download image/captcha
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='trRandom3']/td[2]/img")
get_captcha(driver, img, "captcha.jpeg")
```

(Note that I've changed the code little bit so it could works in your case.)

Answer (score 20):

You can get the rendered image of the captacha with a piece of Javascript. It is faster than taking and cropping a screenshot:

```
import base64
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_script_timeout(10)

driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

driver.switch_to.frame("Main")

# find the captcha element
ele_captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(./@src, 'RandomTxt.aspx')]")

# get the captcha as a base64 string
img_captcha_base64 = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1];
    ele.addEventListener('load', function fn(){
      ele.removeEventListener('load', fn, false);
      var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
      cnv.width = this.width; cnv.height = this.height;
      cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      callback(cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22));
    }, false);
    ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    """, ele_captcha)

# save the captcha to a file
with open(r"captcha.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_captcha_base64))
```

EDIT :

Selenium just removed `find_element_by_xpath` method in version `4.3.0`. See the CHANGES:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/a4995e2c096239b42c373f26498a6c9bb4f2b3e7/py/CHANGES

```
Selenium 4.3.0
* Deprecated find_element_by_* and find_elements_by_* are now removed (#10712)
* Deprecated Opera support has been removed (#10630)
* Fully upgraded from python 2x to 3.7 syntax and features (#10647)
* Added a devtools version fallback mechanism to look for an older version when mismatch occurs (#10749)
* Better support for co-operative multi inheritance by utilising super() throughout
* Improved type hints throughout
```

The method must be changed from

```
ele_captcha = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(./@src, 'RandomTxt.aspx')]")
```

TO :

```
ele_captcha = driver.find_element("xpath", "//img[contains(./@src, 'RandomTxt.aspx')]")
```

Full working script :

```
import base64
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.set_script_timeout(10)

driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

driver.switch_to.frame("Main")

# find the captcha element
ele_captcha = driver.find_element("xpath", "//img[contains(./@src, 'RandomTxt.aspx')]")

# get the captcha as a base64 string
img_captcha_base64 = driver.execute_async_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0], callback = arguments[1];
    ele.addEventListener('load', function fn(){
      ele.removeEventListener('load', fn, false);
      var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
      cnv.width = this.width; cnv.height = this.height;
      cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(this, 0, 0);
      callback(cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22));
    }, false);
    ele.dispatchEvent(new Event('load'));
    """, ele_captcha)

# save the captcha to a file
with open(r"captcha.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_captcha_base64))
```

Comment: This code downloads a new image so the captcha is different.

Comment: cnv.width = ele.width; cnv.height = ele.height; Gives better solution

Answer (score 14):

If you already have image loaded, instead of execute_async_script, go with

```
import base64
img_base64 = browser.execute_script("""
    var ele = arguments[0];
    var cnv = document.createElement('canvas');
    cnv.width = ele.width; cnv.height = ele.height;
    cnv.getContext('2d').drawImage(ele, 0, 0);
    return cnv.toDataURL('image/jpeg').substring(22);    
    """, browser.find_element_by_xpath("//your_xpath"))
with open(r"image.jpg", 'wb') as f:
    f.write(base64.b64decode(img_base64))
```

Comment: Clean answer with no need to install and import heavy-weight libraries. Thanks!

Comment: Best answer. Thank you so much.