# Selenium get captcha image in browser

Tags: python, selenium, captcha, scrape

I'm new to Selenium and webscraping at all, and now I'm having trouble with captchas.

I'm trying to do the proccedures commented in this link:

[Selenium downloading different captcha image than the one in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36636255/selenium-downloading-different-captcha-image-than-the-one-in-browser)

But it's not going well.

**First Problem**

My first problem is about the xpath selector. First, I have tried this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")

# Change frame.
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")


# Download image/captcha.
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*img[2]")
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.jpeg")
```

Basically, I only changed the link. But I don't know if xpath is correctly written, and how can I write it. Using `[2]` inside the "" sounds good, and it was used this way in the link I mentioned, but it doesn't work when I try to replicate it in a response.xpath in a scrapy shell session: `response.xpath(".//img[2]")`. Has to be this way: `response.xpath(".//img")[2]`

The captcha in my link is hard to catch because the corresponding img tag doesn't have any id or class or anything else. Also, it is a .asp format, and I do not know what I can do about it.

**Second Problem**
Then, I have tried this code, which also appeared in other similar searchs

```
from PIL import Image
from selenium import webdriver

def get_captcha(driver, element, path):
    # now that we have the preliminary stuff out of the way time to get that image :D
    location = element.location
    size = element.size
    # saves screenshot of entire page
    driver.save_screenshot(path)

    # uses PIL library to open image in memory
    image = Image.open(path)

    left = location['x']
    top = location['y'] + 140
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height'] + 140

    image = image.crop((left, top, right, bottom))  # defines crop points
    image.save(path, 'png')  # saves new cropped image


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Estado_Index.asp")

# change frame
driver.switch_to.frame("Main")

# download image/captcha
#img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*[@id='trRandom3']/td[2]/img")
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(".//*img[2]")
get_captcha(driver, img, "captcha.png")
```

Again, I'm having problems with xpath, but there is another problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seletest2.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver.switch_to.frame("Main")
  File "/home/seiji/crawlers_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/switch_to.py", line 87, in frame
    raise NoSuchFrameException(frame_reference)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchFrameException: Message: Main
```

The problem is in this line: `driver.switch_to.frame("Main")`
What does it mean?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WebDriverWait` to wait the element, utilize the method `.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it` to switch the `iframe`

Try the bellow code:

```
driver.get("http://sistemas.cvm.gov.br/?fundosreg")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.NAME, 'Main')))
img = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#Table1 img')))
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.jpeg")
```

You need following import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

But your other url is : http://preco.anp.gov.br/include/Resumo_Por_Estado_Index.asp, the captcha element is not in `iframe`. This is the selector:

```
By.CSS_SELECTOR : table img
```

Please implement it with the above code.