# selenium cannot screenshot a web element

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

[image]

I can screenshot a whole page using Firefox.get_screenshot_as_file('2.png'),but when I screenshot a web element using passage.screenshot('1.png'),it alway raise this exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unrecognized command: GET /session/284283fa-53fc-4b33-b329-e6e888dbdcb0/screenshot/{35834cf1-c9c7-4129-99b1-24f30c6b56e6}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're getting this exception because you cannot take a screenshot of just an element in selenium without some third-party libraries or your own code to handle this. See [This stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Which uses a library called PIL to do it:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

fox = webdriver.Firefox()
fox.get('https://stackoverflow.com/')

# now that we have the preliminary stuff out of the way time to get that image :D
element = fox.find_element_by_id('hlogo') # find part of the page you want image of
location = element.location
size = element.size
fox.save_screenshot('screenshot.png') # saves screenshot of entire page
fox.quit()

im = Image.open('screenshot.png') # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']


im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

Comment: it is useful.But I read selenium API [link](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement),web element  has this method `element.screenshot(‘/Screenshots/foo.png’)`,is this API just  cheating thing?

Comment: See this selenium issue explaining that the only browser supporting this is the EdgeDriver currently: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/912

Comment: This method might not work as well as you expect due to image resizing issues while saving.

Answer (score 4):

The screenshot of a web element is not implemented in the Firefox driver. A workaround would be to crop the targeted element from the screenshot:

```
import StringIO
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://stackoverflow.com')

# get the logo element
element = driver.find_element_by_id('hlogo')

# crop to the logo from the screenshot
rect = element.rect
points = [rect['x'], rect['y'], rect['x'] + rect['width'], rect['y'] + rect['height']]
with Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(driver.get_screenshot_as_png())) as img :
    with img.crop(points) as imgsub :
        imgsub.save("c:\\temp\\logo.png", 'PNG')
```

Comment: What browser does support it? I just tried it on Chrome and this doesn't work either.

Comment: The only driver currently supporting it is the EdgeDriver: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/912

Comment: I test 'webelement.screenshot_as_base64()' in phantomjs browser,this method cant work in phantomjs as well.so it seem not just the Firefox problem.