# Selenium get rendered php captcha image

Tags: python, selenium

I trying to parse web page that has captcha. Captcha is generated by PHP:

```
<img src="/captcha.php" border="0" align="absmiddle">
```

What i do:

```
   self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   img = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//table/tbody/tr/td/img')
   scr = img.get_attribute('src')
```

but it contains captcha.php  and i expecting to see base64.

Is there any way to get that image return by php script ?

Comment: Can you use screenshot to save it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37564932/selenium-cannot-screenshot-a-web-element

Comment: yes but after saving it  need to send it to captcha solving service so i cant just send screenshot of whole page. Maybe i can crop screenshot somehow.

Comment: If you read my link from previous comment, you will find how to crop screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python) you can download the image:

```
# download the image
urllib.urlretrieve(src, "captcha.png")
```

Comment: I think you should read "Update" section from that post "The problem with dynamic generated images is that there is a new image generated each time you request it. In that case, you have several options:"

Comment: True.  This is the nature of captcha images.  I assumed that the OP already knew that it'll be a different image each time they request it, and that they know how they want to deal with that behavior.