# Need to download an icon

Tags: selenium

Please let me know how to download an icon in canvas and refer the screenshot for the reference

Pie chat showing the up and down:
[image: Pie chat showing the up and down]

Code trials:
[image: piece of code]

Comment: That's a `canvas` tag so it's not necessarily an image you can "just download". It's generated on the fly by your browser. You can, however, screenshot it and therefore "convert" it to a static image. If you would like to automate that screenshotting, that will take some time but selenium is the tool to do it!

Comment: possible the duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316402/how-to-save-a-canvas-as-png-in-selenium