# R function to capture an HTML canvas as image

Tags: r, web-scraping

**Background:**
I am writing a script to analyze Minecraft worlds for biome diversity. For a given seed (say, `535310562`), I can obtain a map of the world as an HTML Canvas from https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder#535310562. I would like to download the canvas using R, and then count the number of unique colors  (each color represents a different biome) to determine the number of biomes present.

**Problem:**
I don't know how to analyze pixels in an HTML Canvas using R.

**Possible solutions:**
I've thought of two ways of solving this problem. First, If there's a way to iterate through the pixels in an HTML Canvas using R, the problem becomes trivial. Second, I could first download the image as a gif/bmp/png and read the pixel values from the downloaded image.

**Progress so far:**
I know how to index the canvas node using *rvest*, but I don't know where to go from here.

```
if (!require("rvest")) install.packages("rvest")
randomSeed <- floor(runif(1,-2147483648,2147483647))
urlBase <- paste("https://www.chunkbase.com/apps/biome-finder#",randomSeed,sep="")
biome_wbpg <- read_html(urlBase)
canvas <- html_node(biome_wbpg,"canvas")
```

Comment: Drawing to a canvas is done via javascript and `rvest` doesn't run javascript code, it just downloads raw data from websites. If you need to interact with a canvas element, you'll need to use something like RSelenium to basically run a web browser through R. Questions like this might also help you get started: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316402/how-to-save-a-canvas-as-png-in-selenium