# x y coordinate of interactive chart using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, trading

I am trying to get the element of the individual candles on a tradingview.com chart. specifically they x and y coordinates. Problem is using inspector I cannot get the individual candles to show as their own element.

I am aware of using

```
location = element.location
```

which if the element were the candle I could get But cant locate the xpath to individual candles

Any help ? Thanks

[link](https://www.tradingview.com/chart/vKzVQllW/)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the stock chart is an element from [Canvas](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp) type:

[image]

As you can notice, the content appears at the DOM as a whole, and you cannot track any child elements such as candles. 
To make further analysis of the Canvas, I advise to take a snapshot of it in your code using open-source library like [ashot](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/ashot), and for python look at [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224293/how-to-screenshot-a-specified-webelement-in-selenium-using-python). Then you would be capable of inspecting the candles by their RGB code within the image, as well as getting their coordinates.