# How to get the size and document location of a Tweet container

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium, parsing

I am trying to take a screenshot of a tweet from its link. I am planning to use Selenium for it. However, I am not sure how to find the location of a certain tweet from its link. I will use that location to crop the image. Do you have any advices for this task or should I change my approach to the problem?

What I mean by container is the part of the web page that contains this:

Link to the original tweet: https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1250091410424037380]
[image: Link to the original tweet: https://twitter.com/Twitter/status/1250091410424037380]

Comment: Have you tried the Twitter API? https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs

Comment: @Frank I searched it but it doesn't provide that specific information unfortunately.

Comment: Check the Tweet object, it has coordinates and place: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/tweet-object

Comment: @Frank it is geographic location. I am trying to find the location in the document.

Comment: I see I misunderstand it. See if this one helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832322/how-to-capture-the-screenshot-of-a-specific-element-rather-than-entire-page-usin

Comment: @Frank Thank you! Resolved. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224293/how-to-screenshot-a-specified-webelement-in-selenium-using-python