# Selenium Screen Scraping - Python

Tags: python, selenium, screenshot

Trying to take a screenshot of a captcha at the following site: https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/index

I'm trying to screen scrape because I can't seem to download the picture.

See code below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image

fox = webdriver.Firefox()
fox.get('https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/index')
fox.maximize_window()

element = fox.find_element_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'createimage.png?timestamp=')]")

location = element.location
size = element.size

fox.get_screenshot_as_file('screenshot.png')
save_screenshot('screenshot.png')

im = Image.open('screenshot.png') # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)) # defines crop points
im.save('screenshot.png') # saves new cropped image
```

Comment: *I can't seem to download the picture* ...how did you try?

Comment: You're saving the screenshot twice and then opening it again, before cropping it and re-saving. There's no need to do that.
Also, you're not taking the browser chrome into account when you're calculating your crop area.

Comment: @ Aaron, how do I take the browser into account when calculating the crop area?

Comment: @Andersson  Please see question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49258718/downloading-image-using-selenium-in-python-3

Comment: What happens, any exceptions? You have changed the source code taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python. Why? `fox.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')` should do the job.

Answer (score 0):

The captcha image doesn't appear in browser window with default dimensions 800x600. You need to resize window with the following:

```
fox.set_window_size(1800, 1024)
fox.maximize_window()
fox.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')
```