# Scrapy splash: screenshot specific element

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, splash-screen, webpage-screenshot

Is there a way to screenshot a specific element in splash? I cannot seem to find a solution for this, The only option that I found is using "render.png" which takes a screenshot of the full page, I only need a specific element for example "//table".

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python) which I am currently using (solution in selenium), Splash seems faster with less overhead.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this :

```
return splash:select('#my-element'):png()
```

for more details look [document](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/scripting-ref.html?highlight=png#splash-png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that by using scrapy-splash plugin.

https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash
Please read the "More complex Splash Lua Script example - get a screenshot of an HTML element by its CSS selector (it requires Splash 2.1+). Note how are arguments passed to the script:" part there.

You do not use render.png endpoint, you use execute endpoint and execute a lua script to get a screenshot of a specific element.

I implemented it like this in scrapy spider.

```
  def start_requests(self):
  print('parse_start_url')
  yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse_result,
                        endpoint='execute',
                        args={
                            'lua_source': script,
                            'pad': 32,
                            'css': 'body'
                        }
                        )

 script = """
 -- Arguments:
 -- * url - URL to render;
 -- * css - CSS selector to render;
 -- * pad - screenshot padding size.

 -- this function adds padding around region
 function pad(r, pad)
 return {r[1]-pad, r[2]-pad, r[3]+pad, r[4]+pad}
 end

-- main script
function main(splash)

-- this function returns element bounding box
local get_bbox = splash:jsfunc([[
function(css) {
  var el = document.querySelector(css);
  var r = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return [r.left, r.top, r.right, r.bottom];
}
]])

assert(splash:go(splash.args.url))
assert(splash:wait(0.5))

-- don't crop image by a viewport
splash:set_viewport_full()

local region = pad(get_bbox(splash.args.css), splash.args.pad)
return splash:png{region=region}
end
"""
```