# How to save partial screenshot from selenium and opencv in python

Tags: python, selenium, numpy, opencv, crop

I am trying to save particular element from html to be saved as image file using OpenCV and selenium. But unable to save the file.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import cv2
import numpy as np


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(<URl with image>)

# Element to be saved
element = browser.find_element_by_id(<id of element>)

png = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
location = element.location
size  = element.size

nparr = np.frombuffer(png, np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

im = img[left:right, top:bottom]

cv2.imwrite('filename.png',im)
```

Currently there is no image data in `'filename.png'` by running this script.

Comment: can you debug the values stored in `left`, `top`, `right` and `bottom`

Comment: `>>>print (left, top, right, bottom)  >>>755 405 987.0 482.0`

Comment: it would be better if you convert `right` and `bottom` to integer. Also can you debug `print img.shape`  as well? One thing to note here is that you are cropping the `img` numpy matrix in wrong way, correct way of doing the same is `im= img[top:bottom, left:right]`

Comment: Thanks that resolves the issue.

Comment: duplicate of [How to take partial screenshot with Selenium WebDriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to take partial screenshot with Selenium WebDriver in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @Zdar I am writing the solution below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import cv2
import numpy as np


browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(<URl with image>)

# Element to be saved
element = browser.find_element_by_id(<id of element>)

png = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
location = element.location
size  = element.size

nparr = np.frombuffer(png, np.uint8)
img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)


left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']

#im = img[left:right, top:bottom]
im = img[top:int(bottom), left:int(right)]
cv2.imwrite('filename.png',im)
```