# scraping text rendered into a svg graphic (to deter scrapers) - how to?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, screen-scraping

So this time in my scraping escapades I've encountered a new foe - a website which deters scrapers by "transforming" the price data everyone would like to scrape into SVG images. A simple question - what is the "preferred" tool or method of scraping such a site **continously**? I thought of  downloading full page screenshots with Selenium (with stealth, since the site also has cloudflare scrape detection) and OCR'ing it with tesseract but downloading alone takes about 7 seconds per page (and I have 180 of them to scrape) so while that isn't completely unworkable, it is below expectations, so to speak.

My question is, what are the general methods, techniques or tools I should be looking at to tackle this task? Is there a way of OCR'ing the SVGs directly on the site without having to download them somehow/making screenshots? Or what should I be looking at?

for reference, what I'm trying to scrape is for example this - https://www.goatbots.com/set/kaldheim , the "buy" and "sell" columns

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking the screenshots of the price elements only instead of taking complete page screenshot. [Check this post for partial screenshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15018372/how-to-take-partial-screenshot-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python)

As for OCR'ing it with tesseract is the best free option.

For cloudflare use chrome undetected driver for python which is very much successful in bypassing cloudflare.