# Take Screenshot of iframe Element using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, iframe

I am working on "selenium webdriver" with java. I can switch to iframe. I can read the Element which is inside iframe. But i want to take the screenshot of Element which is inside iframe. Am using the following code. Its not take screenshot inside iframe element. There is any solution for this.

```
File screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
BufferedImage  fullImg = ImageIO.read(screenshot);
Point point = ele.getLocation();
int eleWidth = ele.getSize().getWidth();
int eleHeight = ele.getSize().getHeight();
BufferedImage eleScreenshot= fullImg.getSubimage(point.getX(), point.getY(), eleWidth,eleHeight);
ImageIO.write(eleScreenshot, imageType, screenshot);
```

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10848900/2932244) might help

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am using same code above. Its not capture iframe Element..

Comment: You didn't include the code for assigning `ele`... did you switch to the frame and then assign `ele`?

Comment: Thanks JeffC. I forgot to add the code. your question solved my issue. I switch frame to current iframe parent. Now its working fine.